# Slideshow2 Mootools problem in IE

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, mootools

im trying to implement [Slideshow2](http://www.electricprism.com/aeron/slideshow/) but I have problems with IE, as you can see in this test: http://kb.muscarienlinea.com/mo/ the Slideshow works ok in FF and Chrome, but is not working on IE7

What im missing? Thxs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this might be a shot in the dark but try removing the last comma from your data var.

```
var data = {
  '1.png': { href: '/1/' },
  '2.png': { href: '/2/' },
  '3.png': { href: '/3/' }
};
```

Note: this fixes the problem but now there seems to be a black border showing up, this might be fixed by using png with transparency.